# How to address SpecFlow Scenario Outlines with too many parameters?

Tags: functional-testing, specflow, regression-testing

We are using SpecFlow for functional tests that suppose to replace manual testing when a human reads generated email and validates that all sections match specification. The problem is that  Scenario Outlines become to grow to have too many parameters

```
Scenario Outline: generate and send confirmation email 
       Given I have stored itinerary in  '<EmbeddedItinerary>'
       When Generate confirmation email

       Then section1 should have   parameters '<Param1_1>', '<Param1_2>', '<Param1_3>',...
       Then section2 should have   parameters '<Param2_1>', '<Param2_2>', '<Param2_3>',..
       Then section3 should have   parameters '<Param3_1>', '<Param3_2>', '<Param3_3>',...
....
```

Examples:

```
  | EmbeddedItinerary | Param1_1| Param1_2|  Param1_3| Param2_1| Param2_2| Param2_3| Param3_1| Param3_2| Param3_3|...

| Itinerary_1 |  Value1_1 | Value1_2 |  Value1_3 | Value2_1 | Value2_2 |  Value2_3 |Value3_1 | Value3_2 |  Value3_3 |...
| Itinerary_1 |  Value1_1 | Value1_2 |  Value1_3 | Value2_1 | Value2_2 |  Value2_3 |Value3_1 | Value3_2 |  Value3_3 |...
```

But the number of columns in Examples would become unmanageable. I wish to have multi-line examples ( but with different reason then in [Multiple Multi-Line Examples in SpecFlow Feature File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191178/multiple-multi-line-examples-in-specflow-feature-file)).

The option that I see is to store all ExpectedResults in embedded xml or json resource file, and have SpecFlow features quite small e.g.

```
Scenario Outline: generate and send confirmation email with correct email address for flight section
       Given I have stored embedded resource '<EmbeddedItinerary>'
       When Generate confirmation email 
       Then sections should be as specified in '<ExpectedResultsFile>'
Examples: 
| EmbeddedItinerary   |  ExpectedResultsFile

| Itinerary_1 |  ExpectedResults1 |
| Itinerary_2 |  ExpectedResults2 |
...
```

Is it a good idea?
Can anyone suggest better way ( more SpecFlow style)?
My concern is that moving expected data to separate files I am loosing visibility, that is one of advantages of SpecFlow features.

Update: while writing this question I found  commercial product ($AUD 255 per user)  Specflow+Excel   http://www.specflow.org/plus/excel/getting-started/  , which may satisfy my requirement to maintain   many columns.
Is it a mature/reliable product?   Should I use it instead of own parsing   expected results files in proprietary  format?

Answer (score 2):

If I have a lot of parameters in a Scenario Outline, I try to work as much as possible with default parameters or split the Scenario Outline in multiple ones.

I think in your case, it should be possible to split the one 'generate and send confirmation email' Scenario Outline in multiple ones that you have a scenario outline for every section.

This would reduce the amount of needed parameters per scenario and you get faster feedback if an error occurs. You immediately see in which section you have an error.

e.g.:

```
Scenario Outline: generate and send confirmation email - section 1
     Given I have stored itinerary in  '<EmbeddedItinerary>'
     When Generate confirmation email

     Then section1 should have   parameters '<Param1_1>', '<Param1_2>', '<Param1_3>',...

Examples:
    | EmbeddedItinerary | Param1_1  | Param1_2 | Param1_3 | 
    | Itinerary_1       |  Value1_1 | Value1_2 | Value1_3 | 


Scenario Outline: generate and send confirmation email - section 2
     Given I have stored itinerary in  '<EmbeddedItinerary>'
     When Generate confirmation email

     Then section2 should have   parameters '<Param2_1>', '<Param2_2>', '<Param2_3>',..

Examples:
    | EmbeddedItinerary | Param2_1 | Param2_2 | Param2_3 | 
    | Itinerary_1       | Value2_1 | Value2_2 | Value2_3 |


Scenario Outline: generate and send confirmation email - section 3
     Given I have stored itinerary in  '<EmbeddedItinerary>'
     When Generate confirmation email

     Then section3 should have   parameters '<Param3_1>', '<Param3_2>', '<Param3_3>',...

Examples:
    | EmbeddedItirerary | Param3_1 | Param3_2 | Param3_3 |
    | Itinerary_1       | Value3_1 | Value3_2 | Value3_3 |
```

---

About SpecFlow+Excel: That is also an option. Maintaining examples in Excel is most of the time easier than in the feature- file. It will at least solve your problem in short term, but you have to be also careful to write scenarios that are still understandable and readable.

You can get a trial license for it from here: http://www.specflow.org/request-your-specflow-trial-license/

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow+ (Runner & Excel).

Comment: Thanks, Andreas, one of my colleagues wants to do the same way. My concern is that the actual business scenario is to send an email with all sections and ensure that all sections are correct. Your approach to split it into separate scenarios to test each section individually is more like unit testing, that we do anyway(but without SpecFlow) . Am I wrong?

Comment: It depends on your definition of Unit for an UnitTest. Normally it is a class, so that you are testing the behavior of a single class without dependencies. If more than that is involved in the automated test, you are starting to call it integration test. As you are generating text and sending eMails, I assume that you have here more than one class. Which means you have an integration test.

Comment: How to decide which values have to be tested in the same test, depends on your code. If you always get the same content of an section, whatever other section you check first, it does not matter for the result if you are checking them in one scenario or in multiple.
But if e.g. section2 is dependent that you first check section1, then you need to check them all in one scenario, because section1 is newer access if you separate them.

Comment: What you could do to be on the safe side, is that after you split the scenario outline in multiple for every section, you write one scenario for only a single example where you check all sections.
So you can check that every section alone is generated correctly and that you are generating the whole eMail correct. For the last one, not all examples are needed, because you already know that the content is correct. It only checks if the eMail as a whole is correct.